# Avoiding two instance in android

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

I am developing document editor in android which has DashBoard as MainActivity and i will open Editor which is another activity for editing. I also allow to open the documents in sdcard by putting entries like

```
<data
    android:host="*"
    android:mimeType="*/*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\.doc"
    android:scheme="file" />
```

Now the issue is, first I opened DashBoard, then i pressed device home button which makes the activity pause state. I move to sdcard and open the document which creates another DashBoardActivy to import the file. How to avoid creating two instances?

Comment: You've received many good answers to your previous questions. If they solved the problem for you, please mark them as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify a [`launchMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for `DashBoardActivity` in your manifest. Choosing the correct mode depends on the behavior that you want. For example, `singleInstance` will ensure that only one instance of `DashBoardActivity` ever gets created:

```
<activity [...] android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```

However, that also means that you can only use the activity for one purpose. A similar option that's less restrictive is `singleTop`.

Comment: If dashboard activity opens editor activity then editor will be in top of stack. If I again create dashboard by opening documents in device, how it will behave

Comment: When you open a document, the same instance of `DashBoardActivity` will be placed at the top of the stack.

Comment: In this case, after pressing home button when opening document from device file Explorer, the dashboard activity onRestart() will be called. But i don't get the path of selected file there(like bundle in onCreate).

Comment: The `onNewIntent()` method in your activity will be called when the activity is restarted. You can override that method and retrieve the selected file path from the new `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

The case you just referred to can be avoided if you mark it in manifest file as 
**launchMode=singleTop**
but this will in the case you mentioned ***"like you pressed the home button"*** that will keep the previous instance in the back stack, so this time when you try to start the activity the previous instance **(sitting at the top of the backstack )** will be used.

**stack** : INSTANCE1 
**actionperformed**:press home button

stack remains the same
**stack**: INSTANCE1

**actionperformed**:try to launch the activity again for new document
**stack**: INSTANCE1(is again activated via onNewIntent())

so now as INSTANCE1 is at the top,no new instance will be launched as it is marked single top

for more info visit 
[android document for these flags](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

hope it helps